How to obtain the trading volume of smaller Solana tokens like memecoins using Python?
I am developing an application to collect information on memecoins on the Solana network and am already using libraries such as solders and solana-py. However, I have not yet found a viable way to find information about volume. Currently, I am using the token pool ID to check transactions involving the specified pool using the get_signatures_for_address method to obtain the hashes, and then examining the contents of these hashes with get_transactions. However, checking each transaction individually is taking too long.

what do you need the signatures and hashes for?

I need to find the signatures and hashes because I need the hash to retrieve the transaction details, such as pre- and post-token balances, to be able to infer the volume.

If it's too slow to check transactions one by one, you have a few options:

rent a private RPC node so the calls to getTransaction go more quickly
fetch whole blocks with getBlock and search for the transactions you want: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblock
run your own validator with a custom Geyser plugin to filter out any transactions: https://docs.solanalabs.com/validator/geyser

